# Why does Surefire fail to pick up my JUnit 5 tests in Quarkus and starting from version 3.0.0-M5

Tags: junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

In my Quarkus project I work with a stock standard Quarkus setup of a project (https://code.quarkus.io/) and some internal libraries that rule JUnit 5 dependencies we use in all out projects. When I switch to using Surefire 3.0.0-M5 (or higher) I keep on bumping into that fact that Surefire does not pick up the JUnit 5 tests. When I add a JUnit 4 test (just to test) it does get picked up and executed.

Can anyone help out, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the release notes of Surefire 3.0.0-M6 I bumped into [SUREFIRE-2036](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-2036) which revered to [SUREFIRE-2033](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-2033) which mentioned that I might have a superfluous dependency on `junit-platform-runner` on my classpath. When I removed this dependency (using an exclude on the transitive dependency from the internal library): JUnit 5 tests were executed again.